# FileChooser getAttachement only from this Folder

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

How to make the user to select the file from only specified folder

```
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(FileChooser.this);

if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    source = file.getAbsolutePath();
    fileName = file.getName();
    attachText.setText(fileName);
    source = source.replace("\\","\\\\");                
}
```

Here I will get the file from any folder, where I want the file only from G:\Project\Attachments. How Can i do this?

Comment: `FileChooser.this` what is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File dir = new File("G:\\Project\\Attachments");
FileSystemView fsv = new SingleRootFileSystemView(dir);
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(fsv);
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);

if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
```

Comment: +1, although SingleRootFileSystemView is not a standard class. Maybe you are referring to the class found in [Single Root File Chooser](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/single-root-file-chooser/)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the directory in the constructor:

```
JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser(theDirectory);
```

or set it

```
filechooser.setCurrentDirectory(theDirectory);
```

in **your case** the directory is:

```
File theDirectory = new File("G:\\Project\\Attachments");
```

Comment: @vijay this would allow user to go out of directory and select other file.